# App Rejection by Apple due to use of watchdog timer for applications in unity3d iOs Game?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I got a rejection from apple due to the following issue.

2.2: Apps that exhibit bugs will be rejected

We found that your app failed to launch on iPhone 4 and iPad 2 running iOS 5,on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.

We encountered the issue when selecting the application on the Home screen - the app displayed a launch image then quit unexpectedly. This may be because iOS 4 uses a watchdog timer for applications; if an application takes too long to complete its initial startup, the operating system terminates the application.

Right now I am confuse. What should I do. Please suggest me the right way.

Comment: I had this same thing happen to an app of mine too. I had a previous rejection for some small graphical thing, then upon resubmission I get this back (so I know they've been able to run the app previously, and it wasn't happening everytime). I simply tested again, saw no problem (didn't expect to see one, the app is super stable and has never experienced immediate crashes like that), resubmitted, and got through.  I suspect something was simply up with the state of that particular testers device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello friends I got the solution. And I had successfully submitted the game on the appstore.

Here I am using a Preloading code for Decrease the Initial Loading time. And I had just put a Blank scene for indicating the application is running. In earlier time it was taken 36 seconds for that. but right now it is 11 seconds for whole levels.

Thanks